# Custom oAuth client in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am confused about how to build the custom oauth client in asp.net mvc 5.

In mvc 4 it was a simple operation. Implementing custom class from IAuthenticationClient. And then in AuthConfig.cs call the function OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient. But how it can be done in mvc 5?

Comment: Take look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mvc5 authentication is built on Katana (OWIN components by Microsoft). Check following article for detailed overview of Authentication changes in MVC5.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-custom-oauth-middleware-for-mvc-5